# GoLang parsing string to struct

Tags: go, parsing

How do I convert a string to a structure?

The line looks like this: `Name[data1] Name2[data1 data2 data3] Name3[data1 data2]  ...`

The data can be of type Int, String, or Float. In general, this is not important, you can write everything as string.

Data in brackets is separated by a space

What I got using regexp:

```
func Parse() {
    str := "Version[2f0] Terminal[10002] Machine[10.1.1.1] DH[0.137%] Temp[45] Fan[0] Vo[4074 4042 4058 4098] CRC[0 0 0 0]"
    j := make(map[string][]string)

    re, err := regexp.Compile(`(?P<Name>[^ \[]*)\[(?P<Value>[^\]]*)`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    res := re.FindAllSubmatch([]byte(str), -1)
    for _, match := range res {
        j[string(match[1])] = strings.Split(string(match[2]), " ")
    }

    log.Printf("%+v", j)
}
```

Could there be a more elegant way using json.Unmarshal?

Comment: read any basic guide to go for example here is the section on structs from "a tour of go" https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/1

Answer (score 1):

If you're free to use any tool you like, a regular expression might make this fairly easy.

```
(?P<Name>\[^\[\]*)\[(?P<Values>\[^\]\]*)\]
```

[That matches each of the named value sets](https://regex101.com/r/hJEvhb/1).

and then you could split the `Values` group at the spaces with [`string.Split`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split)

To create a [dynamic struct you'd need to use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559250/golang-dynamically-creating-member-of-struct). Avoid reflection, though, as you learn Go.  A `struct` in Go is unlike  an object in say Javascript or Python, where fields are dynamic at runtime.  Go `struct`s are meant to have static fields.

For this purpose, a `map[string][]string` would be a more appropriate type.  The key would be the `Name` fields, and the value would be the `data` fields.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to define a specific format for the serializing the data. A key part of that will be how to encode specific special characters, such as the `[` and `]`. You generally do not want to do this.
2. If you want to use *any* string as a temporary textual representation of your data and the format doesn't matter, you can just use JSON and use `json.Marshal()` and `json.Unmarshal()`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve (what's this struct data? what generated it? why are you trying to decode it into a struct?) but it seems that going through the fundamentals might be helpful:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization will tell you what that is
- https://betterprogramming.pub/serialization-and-deserialization-ba12fc3fbe23 is a very short guide that will give you the very basics (in JavaScript)
- I already mentioned `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal` - reading their docs in the standard library will be helpful as well.

I'm sure you can google the more in-depth articles when you identify what you need to know for your specific purposes.